# Custom Routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, custom-routes

So I have routing scheme like below.
When URIlooks like "`audi-a4-modification-category`" - it work's fine.
But when I have uri like "`alfa-romeo-giulietta-modification-category`", 
becouse Laravel thinks alfa - brand, romeo - model ... and I'm getting wrong method from controller. How can I fix that, without changing delimiter in URI?

```
Route::get('{brand}-{model}-{modification}-{category}', 'Frontend\PagesController@category')->middleware('custom-routing')->name('frontend.category');
Route::get('{brand}-{model}-{modification}', 'Frontend\PagesController@modification')->middleware('custom-routing')->name('frontend.modification');
Route::get('{brand}-{model}', 'Frontend\PagesController@model')->middleware('custom-routing')->name('frontend.model');
Route::get('{brand}', 'Frontend\PagesController@brand')->middleware('custom-routing')->name('frontend.brand');
```

Comment: please format better your post

Comment: Is `alfa_romeo` an option?

Answer (score 0):

The laravel docs state the following:

> Route parameters are always encased within {} braces and 
>   should consist of alphabetic characters, and may not contain a - character. 
>   Instead of using the - character, use an underscore (_).

More info:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters

A workaround would be to replace the url parts before generating the url:

**The route:**

```
Route::get('{brand}-{model}-{modification}-{category}', 'Frontend\PagesController@category')->middleware('custom-routing')->name('frontend.category');
```

**The link:**

```
<a href="{{ route('frontend.category', [str_replace('-', '_', 'alfa-romeo'), 'giulietta', 'modification', 'category']) }}">test</a>
```

The controller:

```
class PagesController
{
    public function category(...$args)
    {
        // or use list(...)
        [$brand, $model, $modification, $category] = array_map(function($urlPart) {
            return str_replace('_', '-', $urlPart);
        }, $args);

        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a mutator in model, something like

```
protected $appends = ['slug'];
```

and

```
public function getSlugAttribute() {
    $slug = $this->brand . '-' . $model . '-' . $modification . '-' . $category;
    return $slug;
}
```

now, it is just a model property and you can use route-model binding concept

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

all in your eloquent model and in controller

```
public function show(YourModel $slug) {
    return $slug;//your model instance
}
```

Not tested, but it should work fine.